# Are state migrations in Terraform supported for both resources and data sources?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, hashicorp

I found [Resources - State Migration](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/sdkv2/resources/state-migration) tutorial that describes the process of implementing a state migration for resources and it worked perfectly for me when I implemented it for `foo` ***resource***.

However when I tried to implement the same thing for `foo` ***data source*** where I literally *reused* the same upgrader methods (since the migration is the same for both resource and data source):

```
SchemaVersion: 1,
StateUpgraders: []schema.StateUpgrader{
    {
        Type:    resourceExampleInstanceResourceV0().CoreConfigSchema().ImpliedType(),
        Upgrade: resourceExampleInstanceStateUpgradeV0,
        Version: 0,
    },
},
```

I'm running into a `.bar: missing expected [` error when trying to run `terraform plan` for an existing TF state with a data source (version 0) and updated `main.tf` that contain an updated definition of `foo` data source that matches its updated schema.

Here's

```
func resourceExampleInstanceStateUpgradeV0(ctx context.Context, rawState map[string]interface{}, meta interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    barString := rawState["bar"].(string)
    rawState["bar"] = []interface{}{map[string]interface{}{
        "name": barString,
    }}
    return rawState, nil
}
```

I might be able to come up with a fully reproducible example that will include more code but I figured it might be useful to ask about it more generally since the tutorial named "Resources - State Migration" and not "Data Sources - State Migration".

On the other hand,

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "mode": "data",
      "type": "bar",
      "name": "example",
      ...
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 0,
```

contain `schema_version` still so it might be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Data resources do not require state migrations. They are read-only resources, so the action of reading them updates the state to the latest version. For this reason, Terraform does not call the `UpgradeResourceState` method for data sources.

> I’m not sure what is going on the legacy SDK when using `StateUpgraders` on a data source, the error looks like it might be from json decoding? That may be something they can prevent in the schema validation.

[The reference](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/do-data-sources-support-state-migrations/37305/2)